# Prevent modal dialog/div from going off screen

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div centered on the screen and I'd like to prevent it from going off screen. I've seen similar question here on SO, but in my case I don't know the size of the div so I align it using translate/transform.

But when the browser window gets smaller than the div height it goes off screen.

I hoped that adding "max-height: 100vh" will solve the problem, but it doesn't.

Is it possible to keep the whole div on the screen somehow, preferably with CSS?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        .dialog {
            min-width: 200px;
            min-height: 150px;
            position: absolute;

            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

            /* Should not be set! */
            /* width: 100px; */
            /* height: 100px; */

            max-height: 100vh;
            overflow-y: auto;

            background-color: #aaa;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="dialog">
        First <br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />last
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a media query to the same `min-height` of your dialog and change the `min-height`.

```css
.dialog {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: absolute;

  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;

  background-color: #aaa;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 150px) {
  .dialog {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dialog">
    First <br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />last
  </div>
</body>
```